# extract pdf data and fill php form fields using php and ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, pdf

I need some help for complete my project,
how to extract PDF file data and auto fill HTML or PHP form when i'm uploading a file. suppose this is my PDF file and in the red box is my data which is import in my html form.

[image]

Comment: I think extract data form pdf file is quite difficultly. Why dont you push data via form normally?

Comment: actually client needs both mode, 2nd option for if any deal or contract  sign for company so that time they upload pdf file and our form grab all data form deal or contract pdf file.